# Embed Javascript for a site collection in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, scriptlink

What is best practice to embed javascript for an SPO site collection?

I was hoping to run the OfficeDev/PnP [Core.EmbedJavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/customize-your-sharepoint-site-ui-by-using-javascript) but it requires side loading of apps.

1. I'm looking for a recommendation that temporary side loading of apps with respect to the above is okay (I need to convince IT operations dept.)
2. Another way of embedding javascripts.

Comment: Not a lot blogged about, search for ``user custom actions scriptlink``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was wrong - I have asked on the Microsoft Tech Community, SharePoint Developer and this is the answer from Vesa Juvonen:

> I would never call anything as a "best practice", since it depends on some many factors. Core.EmbedJavaScript is PnP scenario sample to show how to use embed JavaScript pattern on the existing sites. Key objective of this sample is to show the APIs on adding userCustomAction with custom JavaScript to your tenant.
>
> Sample does use provider hosted add-in/app only for the demo purposes - in real production, I'd never personally implement this as a functionality where you'd need to explicitly go and click a button in app/add-in to make things happen.
>
> "ok - so how then?" - Typically these kind of customizations are pushed to site using remote provisioning pattern. You could use PnP PowerShell or even console application to call the needed operation, if you'd like to get the sites modified. This would only require needed permissions to the site, but would not require any app/add-in side loading steps.
>
> So in simplicity, you have pretty much following options for automating this
>   Perform the needed customization as part of the your site creation - if you use self-service site creation or admin operations using PnP PowerShell / console application
>
> Perform needed customization as a admin operation to existing sites - if you don't have custom site provisioning process for your customers - can be a PowerShell script or console application
>   So - you do not need to have side-loading enabled for the production sites, since in practice you'd not actually deploy the add-in to the sites, since APIs are exposed using CSOM for accessing them with alternative models.
>
> Makes sense?

You can find the post [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Embed-JavaScript-by-side-loading-of-app/m-p/12946).

So I used a console application to remotely provision JavaScripts to my SPO SC.

Answer (score 0):

This video can give you some ideas to convince your IT operation department.

[JS injection in SPO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/JavaScript-injection-in-SharePoint-Online-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices)

It seems the Script Editor webpart is not available in SPO

Comment: Thanks, but are you agreeing with me that side loading is the way to go?

Comment: Sorry I thought you want to convice the IT Dept to use the Microsoft way.

Comment: What about using CSS / MasterPage (it is not included in the MS best practices ):
http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online
 https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/09/05/revised-a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding-part-2-with-javascript/

Comment: you are right about the video - I first understood it as a developer site practice. Thanks!

Comment: They are still not convinced that this approach is the way to go for a production environment. :( Has anyone seen anything in writing or even better, carved in stone?